# The result of the bi-conditional $\leftrightarrow$ is true when n is odd and m is odd, and when n is even and m is even. Proof by induction

Tags: induction

Let **m** be the number of Truth values for each row, and let **n** be the size of the truth table. $2^n$.  I discovered that the result of the bi-conditional $p1\leftrightarrow p2$ $\leftrightarrow p3$ is true when n is odd and m is odd.

I've also discovered that the result of the bi-conditional $p1\leftrightarrow p2$ $\leftrightarrow p3$ $\leftrightarrow p4$ is true when **n** is even and **m** is even.

How do I prove this using Induction?  I know the base cases the truth table results with odd and even values.  I'm having a hard time creating the formula that I would use to prove by Induction.

"The result of the bi-conditional is true when **n** is odd and **m** is odd"

Please Help!!!! :)

[image: Odd example]

[image: Even example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof sketch of the inductive step:

- Let $m_n$ be the number of true $p_i$ in the chained biconditional $(p_1\iff ... \iff p_n)$. Then your statement is equivalent to saying that the chained biconditional is true if and only if $m_n + n$ is even.
- The biconditional is associative, so we have the following equivalence
  $$
  (p_1\iff ... \iff p_{n+1})\equiv [(p_1\iff ... \iff p_n) \iff p_{n+1}].
  $$
- Assume that $(p_1\iff ... \iff p_n) \iff (m_n+n \mathrm{\,is\,even})$. Use the above equivalence to show that $(p_1\iff ... \iff p_{n+1}) \iff (m_{n+1} + n+ 1 \mathrm{\,is\,even})$.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I can work with that.  I guess if I wanted to prove it for odd and even It would just be a 2 proof process, meaning do it twice, one for even and one for odd?

Comment: @RyBoneCoder No, this is a single proof for all $n$, odd and even. That's why I used the statement "$m_n + n$ is even", as it covers both the odd case ($m_n$ and $n$ both odd) and the even case ($m_n$ and $n$ both even).

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  I didn't see that at first.  Math is my weakness, and this topic is thick for me to wrap my head around.  Thank you so much for the follow-up.

Comment: how do you write those subscripts on this StackExchange.  I'm new to the mathJax and can't figure it out.  I keep doing m_{n+1} and it's not working.

Comment: @RyBoneCoder Works fine for me: $m_{n+1}$. Make sure to put \$ around it.

Comment: $m_{n+1}$ Testing...  Ahh thank you again.  :)