# If $m_n + n$ is true, then prove that $m_{n+1} + n + 1$ is true. Algebraic breakdown help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

I'm a 46 year old Discrete Math student, and with all of the gaps in my math education, remembering the algebra to do the last step of my Induction proofs have been the hardest part for me. How do I deal with the subscript and where do I even start to break the right side of this down to prove that it is equal to the left.  Looking forward to learning this. I have added some example pics of the program that I have created to run the Truth Table examples.  It sums up the total of each row and proves that my theory is correct.

Let $m_n$ be the number of true $p_i$ in the chained bi-conditional $(p_1 \leftrightarrow p_2 ... \leftrightarrow p_n)$

Claim: The chained bi-conditional is true if and only if $m_n + n$ is even for all positive integers. This formula covers both odd and even cases.

$m_n + n$ $\rightarrow$ $m_{n+1} + n + 1$

[image: odd example]

[image: even example]

Comment: What is $m_n$ ?

Comment: $m_n$ is the number of true $p_i$ in the chained bi-conditional logical expression of a truth table.  I've discovered that when the size of the truth table is odd than the bi-conditional $p1 \leftrightarrow$ $p2$ is true when the summed number of trues in each row is odd.  The same applies for even as well.  So my formula is "Claim: The chained bi-conditional is true if and only if $m_n + n$ is even for all (m,n) E positive integers."  That covers both the odd and even scenarios.  This is a proof by induction.  I just can't figure out how to break the algebra down.

Comment: I don't follow.  How does your claim relate to $m_n+n=m_{n+1}+n+1$?  The equals sign there is incredibly suspect.  Are you sure you don't mean to have an $\implies$ or a modulo $2$ or something else along those lines instead?  Honestly, I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what your claim is in the first place.  "Summed number of trues in each row is odd"?  Are you observing how in the truth table $\begin{array}{c|c|c}P&Q&P\iff Q\\ \hline T&T&T\\T&F&F\\F&T&F\\F&F&T\end{array}$ every row has an odd number of trues and are trying to generalize this to higher numbers?

Comment: If that were the case... are you really looking at each row individually?  Note that $F\iff T\iff T$ is false as well as $F\iff F\iff T$ is also false, so your claim seems incorrect.

Comment: My claim is not incorrect.  $F \leftrightarrow F$ == to zero which is even.  The truth table size is $2^n = 2^2$ which is even.  I've studied every size truth table extensively and it holds true for all of them.  This is what I was supposed to discover during a 4 week project.  for a $2^2$ like your example above the result is true on $ m = 2 $ and $ m = 0 $ which are both even.  If you doe a $2^3$ size table you will have to use $p1\leftrightarrow p2 \leftrightarrow p3$ and you will see that it holds true for all odd and so on... $ n=m$. You don't consider the result into the equation.

Comment: Here is a link to some pictures of my work in another post.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583093/the-result-of-the-bi-conditional-leftrightarrow-is-true-when-n-is-odd-and-m-i

Comment: I've finished my entire proof, I don't understand how to finish the algebra to break down my final equation for the very last part.  I have two weeks to figure it out, but I didn't want to wait until last minute.

Comment: You should note that $p_1\iff p_2 \iff p_3$ is not equivalent to $(p_1\iff p_2)\iff p_3$.  The first is generally interpreted as meaning $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are simultaneously all true or are simultaneously all false.  Under such an interpretation, $p_1\iff p_2\iff \cdots \iff p_n$ will be true if and only if "the number of trues in the row is equal to $n$ or is equal to $0$" which is not the same as "the number of trues in the row is odd"

Comment: Now... talking instead specifically about $((\cdots (p_1\iff p_2)\iff p_3)\iff\cdots )\iff p_n)$, the linked post already gave the induction step...

Comment: Thanks @JMoravizt. I interpreted as 'all $p_i$ are equivalent' and was confused about everything. With the brackets as in your comment it suddenly is a really nice question.

Comment: I did do that in my proof paper.  I wasn't that specific in my post here as I was only looking for help with the algebra on my last step.  Also, Python is different with the way that it reads input.  Although the associativity is correct like you point out in the above comment, I had to learn how to input the info correctly to get the output desired.  I did the Truth tables on paper first to understand how I had to interact with Python to trust the out put.  I actually have to use parentheses in python to get ((p1==p2)==p3) to get the result of $(p_1\leftrightarrow p_2\leftrightarrow p_3)$

Comment: I edited my original question to be more specific.  I thought that I would just get the algebra help I was looking for trying to be simple.  I thought if I talked about my whole research it would have scared people away from answering my question.  :)

Comment: @RyBoneCoder Yes computer programs can sometimes feel a bit rigid and annoying with their insistence on putting all the brackets in the right places before they are even willing to listen to you, but in this case putting the brackets in place is actually useful for human readers too.

Comment: In all of the induction that I have been learning in my class the professor always wants us to break down the algebra to show that our final equation that if my assumption is true for our formula that it is also true for +1.  So I have to simplify the right side to back into the left side.   $m_n + n$ $\rightarrow$ $m_{n+1} + n +1$

Comment: About the question's title, the last comment, etc.: Numbers cannot be true. Only statements can be true or false. Numbers cannot imply numbers. Only statements can imply statements.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you want to see the truth of the biconditional

$$P \leftrightarrow p_{n+1}$$ where $P$ itself is a complex chain of smaller statements with arrows between them. The beauty of the situation is that you discovered the a different way of describing the truth or falsehood of $P$: $P$ is true if $m_n + n$ is even and false if it is odd.

This is great. Now we don't have to worry about the inner structure of $P$ and just role with this.

We know that there are just 4 possible situations:

- $P$ is true and $p_{n+1}$ is true
- $P$ is true and $p_{n+1}$ is false
- $P$ is false and $p_{n+1}$ is true
- $P$ is false and $p_{n+1}$ is false

In each of the four situations you can compute two things:

1. Whether the 'big' statement $P \leftrightarrow p_{n+1}$ is true or not.
2. Whether $(n+1) + m_{n+1}$ is even or odd

Once you have done that you can check if the relation between truth/falsehood of the big statment and even/oddness (parity) of $(n+1) + m_{n+1}$ that you conjectured holds in all four cases and if it does you are done.

Now I think you don't have any trouble with item 1. So let's talk about 2.

First: why $(n+1) + m_{n+1}$? Well because there are $n + 1$ terms in the big statement $P \leftrightarrow p_{n+1}$

As I said you want to compute this quantity in four situations. I'll do the first, you can do the other three.

$P$ is true so $n + m_n$ is even. 
Let's distinguish two more cases: $n$ even and $n$ odd.

If $n$ is even then $m_n$, the number of true statements among $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ must be even as well. Now we add the aditional true (IN THIS CASE) statement $p_n$ so we get that $m_{n+1} = m_n + 1$: the total number of true statments is one more so $m_{n+1}$ is odd. On the other hand, since $n$ is even, $n+1$ is odd as well and hence $(n+1) + m_{n+1}$ is odd + odd = even.

If $n$ is odd then, since $n + m_n$ is even, $m_n$ is odd as well. We add one more true statement ($p_n$) so we find (IN THIS CASE) that $m_{n+1}$ is even. But $n + 1$ is even as well (since $n$ is odd) so again $(n+1) + m_{n+1}$ is even.

Conclusion: in the scenario of the first bullet point we have that $(n+1) + m_{n+1}$ is even. One down, three to go.

Comment: As far as what I have left to do in my proof, I need to simplify $m_{n+1} + n + 1$ by using algebraic manipulation and show that it is equal to $m_n + n$.  That is the way my professor is having us do the last portion of our Induction proofs.  I tried as hard as I could not to talk about my proof in this question, but everyone keeps digging.  :) I left a lot out of what I had done in my proof because I needed help with the algebra.  After we come up with our formula, we have to prove that is is also true for + 1, and use algebraic manipulation to turn it back into the original formula.

Comment: What can I do to $m_{n+1} + n + 1$ to simplify it back to $m_n + n$?  Can that be done? Is there a reason no one has tried to explain that to me thus far?

Comment: Ok now I see what is your misunderstanding. $m_{n+1} + (n + 1)$ is NOT equal to $m_n + n$, look for instance at the case of $n = 2$, $p_1$ true, $p_2$ false, $p_3$ true. Then $m_n = m_2$ is the number of true sentences among the first two statements, hence 1 and $m_n + n = 1 + 2 = 3$. On the other hand, $n+1 = 3$ so that $m_{n+1} = m_3$ is the number of true sentences among the first three statements so $m_3 = 2$ in this example $m_{n+1} + (n+1)$ evaluates to $m_3 + 3 = 2 + 3 = 5$. It is clear that $3 \neq 5$ and never will be.

Comment: However: $m_{n+1} + (n+1)$ is OF THE SAME FORM as $m_n + n$. All expressions of that form are expressions $m_1 + 1$, $m_2 + 2$, $m_3 + 3$, $m_4 + 4$, $m_5 + 5$ etc. The claim you want to prove is about numbers of this form, namely that they are even if the corresponding chain of biimplications is true and odd if the corresponding claim of biimplications is false. The idea of induction is that if we know this for $m_3 + 3$ we want to use that knowledge to show it for $m_4 + 4$. And if we know it is true for $m_4 + 4$ we want to use that to show the same statement about $m_5 + 5$ etc

Comment: Now since in each case this steps you take are the same it makes sense to not talk about 4 and 5 but call one of them n so that you can later reuse that proof for other values of n. The important thing to realise is that as soon as you decide that once you assign the name $n$ to one of the numbers, this determines what the other one is called. For instance. Suppose I know that the chains of 4 biimplications are true if and only if $m_4 + 4$ is even and I want to show that a chain of 5 biimplications is true if and only if $m_5 + 5$ is even then I have to choose which number I call $n$.

Comment: Now when I choose $n = 4$ then immediately $5 = n + 1$. No other choice possible. Also $m_4$ becomes $m_n$. And $m_5$ becomes $m_{n+1}$ because $5 = n+1$. But the good news is: if you have such a proof of the 5 variable case based on the 4 variable case and you change systematically all 4's by $n$'s and all 5's by $n+1$s then the resulting proof will be valid AND usable for all other values of $n$ (5, 6, 7, 8, even 9) that you could think of

Comment: In other words: if you can prove the truth of the statement about $m_{n+1} + (n+1)$ based on the (assumed) validity of the same statement about $m_n + n$ that is enough! No more algebra needed

Comment: Vincent, I can not thank you enough for taking the time to explain all of that to me.  You make someone with a weakness of math see the light.  I wish I could buy you a beer for that.  :)

Comment: One thing I don't think everyone is understanding from my proof is that the result of the truth table is not part of my sum.  when n=2 $2^n$ using IFF logincal expression row 1 of the truth table is m=2 (T, T).  The result of True is not factored into the sum of m.  Row 4 where m=0 (F,F) the result of T is not factored in.  The result is NOT part of my proof.  Just where ever there is a result of TRUE what is the sum of each row from just the Truth Table.

Comment: In your example above with size $2^2$  $p_1$ True $p_2$ False there is no $p_3$ . You said that row would be m=2 but you're not understanding my proof.  That row would only be odd m=1.  There's only 2 variables in a $2^2$ Truth table so with the IFF expression only row 1 and 4 have a true result.  Row 1 m==2 and row 4 m==0.  They are both even.  Look at my examples above.  When n is odd $2^3$ The last column is the result and is not part of the sum of m in each row.  Just $p_1 \leftrightarrow p_2 \leftrightarrow p_3$ In each row that results True m= odd with m=3 in the first row.

Comment: With $2^3$ being odd you will see that there is a True result for row 1 m=3, row 4 m=1, row 6 m=1 and row 7 m=1.  I don't think anyone is understanding that.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and explanations.  I sat down and really tried to dissect what you took the time to explain.  I'm in a much better place with this.